# NGINX: 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: nginx, ssl

i setup nginx for proxypass to docker registry, the protocol http works but if i set https i have: `400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`

This is my nginx configuration file:

```
upstream docker-registry {
 server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name docker-registry.mydomain.it;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/docker-registry;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/docker-registry;

 proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;   # required for Docker client sake
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP

 client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads

 # required to avoid HTTP 411: see Issue #1486 (https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1486)
 chunked_transfer_encoding on;

 location / {
     # let Nginx know about our auth file
     auth_basic              "Restricted";
     auth_basic_user_file    docker-registry.htpasswd;
     proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }
 location /_ping {
     auth_basic off;
     proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }
 location /v1/_ping {
     auth_basic off;
     proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This solution helped me. I had already added `proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;`, but it seems `X-Forwarded-Proto` is required for docker-registry.

Answer (score 0):

Th problem was the docker-registry configuration, i have resolved adding the line `-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --insecure-registry localhost:5000` to /etc/sysconfig/docker under `OPTIONS`